# 422 Unprocessable Entity: Can Wiremock create scenario with a missing quotation?

Tags: json, parsing, postman, wiremock, http-status-code-422

I am creating a scenario wherein I'd intentionally remove the quotation in the request body and add the corresponding error message. However, Wiremock returns 422 unprocessable entity. Is there a way I could successfully create this?

Here is my scenario.

```
{
"scenarioName": "Invalid JSON Format",
"name": "testscenarioinvalidformat",
"persistent": true,
"request": {
    "url": "/test/get",
    "method": "POST",
    "headers": {
        "Accept": {
            "contains": "application/json"
        }
    },
    "bodyPatterns": [
        {
            "equalToJson": {
                "test1":"5eHEzEEhT7CuHhdqkt01,
                "test2": "6656gdfgsdf"

            }
        }
    ]
},
"response": {
    "status": 400,
    "jsonBody": {
        "error": {
            "code": 400,
            "message": "Bad Request",
            "detail": {
                "rowCount": 1,
                "row1": {
                    "exception": [
                         "Illegal unquoted character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 13)): has to be escaped using backslash to be included in string value"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
}
```

}

This is the error response

```
{
"errors": [
    {
        "code": 10,
        "source": {
            "pointer": "/request/bodyPatterns/0"
        },
        "title": "Error parsing JSON",
        "detail": "Illegal unquoted character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 13)): has to be escaped using backslash to be included in string value\n at [Source: (String)\"{\r\n    \"scenarioName\": \"Invalid JSON Format\",\r\n    \"name\": \"testscenarioinvalidformat\",\r\n    \"persistent\": true,\r\n    \"request\": {\r\n        \"url\": \"/test/get\",\r\n        \"method\": \"POST\",\r\n        \"headers\": {\r\n            \"Accept\": {\r\n                \"contains\": \"application/json\"\r\n            }\r\n        },\r\n        \"bodyPatterns\": [\r\n            {\r\n                \"equalToJson\": {\r\n                  \"test2\":\"5eHEzEEhT7CuHhdqkt01,\r\n                    \"test2\": \"6656gdfgsdf\"\r\n         \"[truncated 698 chars]; line: 16, column: 50]"
    }
]
```

}

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating your mappings via JSON files, then no, you can't intentionally give it bad JSON as you have. What you *could* do would be to just evaluate the string contents of the request.

```js
"bodyPatterns": [
        {
            "equalTo": "{ \"test1\":\"5eHEzEEhT7CuHhdqkt01,\"test2\": \"6656gdfgsdf\" }"
        }
    ]
```

This may take some time to get up and running, as the string `equalTo` is an exact match. Maybe using `contains` or `matches` would be more appropriate.

Comment: I tried that but it still gives me 422 code error :  (code 92)): was expecting double-quote to start field name\n